# SwiftからObjective-Cのメソッド呼び出し

Tags: objective-c, swift

SwiftからObjective-Cのメソッドを呼ぶ時に、引数がポインタのポインタ「＊＊」の場合、どの様に呼べば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

たとえば

```
-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL
                       options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask
                         error:(NSError **)errorPtr]
```

これは

```
let url: NSURL = // NSURL instance
var error: NSError? = nil // var で宣言。オプショナルにする

let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)
```

のようになります

Answer (score 1):

iBooksで、無料で購読できる、Apple刊行の「[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11)」（リンクは同内容のApple Developのサイト）。
この電子ブックの「Interacting with C APIs」→「Pointers」の項。

C Syntax: Type **
Swift Syntax: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Type>

とあります。
しかし、どういう処理をするかは、じっさいのプログラムコードを見ないと、なんともいえないところです。正直、私自身混乱して、まだよく理解できないままです。